# syntax error when using a variable in jquery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I can't figure out how to use a variable in jquery's animate function. I'm trying to do this:

```
$('#trends_holder').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 300);
```

where left_indent is a variable I've created elsewhere. What am I doing wrong here?

If I output this, I get "invalid token , " and the output code looks like this:

```
$('#trends_holder').animate(, 300);
```

If I trace this:

```
alert (item_count + " | " + item_width + " | " + item_count * item_width);
```

I get a proper value for all of these. But then if I assign a variable to it, it doesn't work:

```
var indent_val = -(item_count * item_width);
$('#trends_holder').animate({'left' : indent_val}, 300);
```

Comment: what's the value of the left_indent var?

Comment: Not sure of your question. That is what's in the source if I view it in the browser. In otherwords left: -300 is not getting output

Comment: are you using some web framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/GqXmy/1/

```
var left_indent = 300;
$('#trends_holder').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 300);
```

Comment: yeah you're right - the code works - I think something in my CMS is changing the code.